# Google sRich Snippets. Redirect from https://schema.org to http://schema.org

Tags: google-rich-snippets

I tried to add data to google rich spinner to my application. I add this code structure

```
return {
    '@context': 'https://schema.org',
    '@type': 'Product',
    'sku': this.currentProduct.sku,
    'category': this.productCategory,
    'name': this.productName,
    'description': this.productDescription,
    'offers': {
      '@type': 'Offer',
      'price': this.bestPrice,
      'priceCurrency': 'USD',
      'availability': this.currentProduct.stock?.is_in_stock ? 'https://schema.org/InStock' : 'https://schema.org/OutOfStock'
    },
    'image': this.thumbnail
  }
```

But if I look to result on search.google.com/test/rich-results I will see that the `availability` field has been assigned a `https://schema.org/InStock` value (not https). why is this happening? Is it important for the project?

Answer (score 1):

It's not an issue. Schema.org are transitioning to use https, but for a long time it was http, and http will with for a long time to come.

[image]